# Searching for ancestor from Malta

Tags: 19th-century, malta

I have found my great grandparent's marriage certificate from 1886 in England. However, he was a merchant seaman. I located a ship record where he was a cook in 1881 and it says he was from Malta. Got on in Calcutta and off in Malta. I am trying to locate him and his family in Malta, but I cant seem to find anything.

His name: Giuseppe (joseph) Piscopo, born approx 1855 or 1856. His father's name was Michael, he was a builder.

Comment: Does the marriage certificate say that he came from Malta?